# vim closetag plugin indent next line

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

For a function, it would be something like

```
function {
    |
}
```

I'm using the vim-closetag plugin, which works fine, but for tags such as `head` which is often styled like such,

```
<head>
    |
</head>
```

vim-closetag doesn't automatically do this, instead it does

```
<head>|</head>
```

Some tags are fine like this, but can I map a command to style the tag like the previous style, line between open and close tag.

Right now I have to manually format it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [C&C++](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp), I have `{` expanded in to `{|}`. I insert the two `\n` only when I hit enter from within a pair of curly-brackets. This way I can decide when I want to go to a new line, or when want oneliners.

You should be able to do the same with html/xml tags.

```
inoremap <buffer> <expr> <cr> getline(".")[col(".")-2:col(".")-1]=="><" ? "<cr><esc>O" : "<cr>"
```

(to be defined in a ftplugin)